Capturing output, stderr and stdout in Snakemake
I am learning snakemake and I do not manage to capture stdout and stderr in the log file.
This is my code:
configfile: "config.json"

rule all:
  input: expand("{sample}.txt", sample = config["samples"])

rule rule1:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        "{sample}.txt"
    log:
        stdout="{sample}.txt.stdout",
        stderr="{sample}.txt.stderr"
    shell:
        "echo {input} > {output} 1> {log.stdout} 2> {log.stderr}"

And the config file is:
{
        "samples":
        {
                "A": "sample1",
                "B": "sample2"
        }
}

sample1 and sample2 are empty files produced by touch.
What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks so much!

Maybe there is a more Snakemake-centric approach, but this works to what I think you were trying to do by adjusting your shell command to send stdout to both places...
configfile: "config.json"
print(expand("{sample}.txt", sample = config["samples"]))
print(lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.sample])

rule all:
  input: expand("{sample}.txt", sample = config["samples"])

rule rule1:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        "{sample}.txt"
    log:
        stdout="{sample}.txt.stdout",
        stderr="{sample}.txt.stderr"
    shell:
        "echo {input} | tee {output} > {log.stdout} 2> {log.stderr}"

My understanding is that log directive and how it works according to the documentation on Log-Files is that it isn't special for programs/commands that don't have a log parameter. The command echo you are toying with doesn't have any log parameter, and so like is discussed at the bottom of the documentation, you are redirecting stdout to a file. However, with your original code "echo {input} > {output} 1> {log.stdout} 2> {log.stderr}" you redirect the stdout to output and then there is no stdout to go to log.stdout. You want to redirect stdout to both output and the log.stdout. See how to use tee here.
Your example doesn't produce any stderr, and so it is expected to be empty.
